# Help with recursive definition for satisfaction in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In Enderton pgs 83-84, he provides a recursive definition for satisfaction in FOL. I am having trouble understanding the clause regarding quantified sentences in FOL.

Let $s:\mathcal{V}\longmapsto|\mathfrak{A}|$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is the set of all variables and $|\mathfrak{A}|$ is the domain of the structure $\mathfrak{A}$.

The clause relating to quantified sentences runs as follows:

$\vDash_\mathfrak{A}\forall x\phi[s]$ iff for every $d\in|\mathfrak{A}|,\vDash_\mathfrak{A}\phi s(x|d) $

And this is how Enderton explains $s(x|d)$:

$s(x|d)$ is exactly like $s$ except for one thing: At the variable $x$, $s(x|d)$ assumes the value $d$.

Also, for clarity, earlier he says informally:

$\vDash_\mathfrak{A}\phi[s]$ iff the translation of $\phi$ determined by $\mathfrak{A}$, where the variable $x$ is translated as $s(x)$ wherever it occurs free, is true.

Intuitively, I understand perfectly what satisfaction requires when it comes to universally quantified sentences. Where I am struggling is on the role played here by $s(x|d)$ in the recursive definition. $s$ is a function that maps all of the variables onto members of the domain. So, the value of $s(x)$ is a member of the domain. And according to Enderton $s(x|d)$ does the same thing. That is, for all variables $y$, the value of $s(x|d)(y)$ is also a member of the domain. Indeed the same member $s(y)$ returns for that variable, unless the variable is $x$, then $s(x|d)(x)=d$.

Part of my confusion is that I don't really understand what $s(x|d)(x)=d$ means. Is $d$ one of the variables here, or is it one of members of the domain? And if the latter, which one? And lastly, I don't see how this move mechanically achieves the intuitive notion of satisfaction for quantified sentences in FOL.

Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't really understand what $s(x|d)(x)=d$ means.

Recall that $s : \text {Var} ⟼ |\mathfrak A|$, where $\text {Var}$ is the set of all variables and $|\mathfrak A|$ is the domain of the structure $\mathfrak A$.

Thjus, $s$ is a function that maps variables into objects of the domain.

What is $d$? An object of the domain: $d \in |\mathfrak A|$.

Thus, if we have a variable assignment function $s$, we will have that:

> $s(x|d)(y)=s(y)$ for $y \ne x$ and $s(x|d)(x)=d$.

This is the gist of: "$s(x|d)$ is exactly like $s$ except for one thing: at the variable $x$ it assumes the value $d$."

---

> How this move achieves the intuitive notion of satisfaction for quantified sentences in FOL?

Exactly because we want that $\forall x P(x)$ is true in a structure when the "meaning" of the *predicate* $P$ holds of every object in the domain of the structure.

Thus, whatever is the value of $s$ for variable $x$, we want that $s$ satisfies $P(x)$ in the structure.

Comment: This is super helpful. A quick follow up: When calculating $s(x|d)(x)$, since $x=x$ we should get $d$. But which $d\in |\mathfrak{A}|$ do we get in that case? Does it matter? And how does this $d$ differ, if it does, from the $d$ we receive for any other variable besides $x$?

Comment: @beachtrees - having a specified $s$, $s(x|d)$ is obviously specified: let $d$ the new value of $s(x)$. In the clause for $\forall$ we want that absolutely **every** $d$ in the domain will do: $P$ holds for every element iff it holds for each one.

Comment: Okay. So what if we just let $s(x|d)(x)=s(x)$? Rather than stipulating that, in this case, $s(x|d)(x)=d$. Isn't $s(x)$ already defined for some $d$? I guess I'm getting hung up on why there's this added wrinkle.

Comment: @beachtrees - the issue is a little bit tricky... we may have other variables free in $\phi$. Thus, we cannot simply say that every $s$ satisfies the formula. We say that: $s$ satisfies $\forall x \phi$ iff whatever value $s'$ assigns to $x$ then $s'$ satisfies $\phi$. The gist is, change the value of $x$ letting all the other values unchanged.

Comment: Oh! I see. So, by letting $s(x|d)(y)=s(y)$ whenever $x\neq y$, we're basically deferring the calculation of satisfaction of $\forall x\phi$ except as pertains to the value $x$ takes on. I.e. if other variables are free in $\phi$, these will be get calculated at other levels of the recursion? So then the $d$ that $s(x|d)$ returns with $x$ as argument is an arbitrary $d\in |\mathfrak{A}|$, i.e. it could be any of them, it doesn't matter which.